# Is it possible to use a Google Earth 3D view, when embedding a google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Or can you embed Google Earth directly even though the  Earth API is deprecated and their documentation page is  mostly disabled. Im trying to have a website that works in the current version of Chrome and uses a 3D google earth. Any way on how I can do this, or are there any alternatives to utilize a 3D globe in your website.( I'm building on rails)  Also  any know why  it was depreciated?

Comment: Heres updated status for this subject : Link : https://developers.google.com/maps/gaming/

Answer (score 5):

At the moment it is not possible to include the Google Earth 3D View with the maps API, but Google already announced that 3D is "in their blood" and so there probably will be an integration into the maps api some day (because the Earth view actually is already included in the official maps web application).

One reason the Google Earth Plugin was deprecated was the fact that the plugin is based on NPAPI and Chrome doesn't support it anymore because of security issues.

A alternative could be [Cesium](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/Terrain.html).